# MQ Server fails: AMQ9637: Channel is lacking a certificate. But Java client is configured to send it

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mq

I've issue with SSL handshake reported on client side as:

```
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
...
    Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException[Remote host closed connection during handshake],3=localhost/127.0.0.1:1414 (localhost),4=SSLSocket.startHandshake,5=default]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1187)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:724)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:400)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:299)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:164)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1598)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:953)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection$6.run(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1156)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection$6.run(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1151)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1149)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
        ... 27 more
```

and on MQ server as:

```
AMQ9637: Channel is lacking a certificate.
```

is obvious that server do not obtain (or accept?) <s>client certificate</s>. That was bad premise, problem was the **server certificate**.

I use:

```
JAVA 7 (1.7.0_75) 
MQ 7.5 client libs (7.5.0.2)
MQ 8.0 server (8.0.0.5)
```

Here is [client Java class](https://github.com/majacz/prototypes/blob/master/mq_ssl/src/main/java/tutorial/mq_ssl/MQSSLTest.java). I try to accept all server certificates, and send the client certificate to MQ server side and same certificate is imported in MQ trust store. Not sure if problem is any restriction for certificate name as is noticed here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg21245474 or if the certificate is really not send to server side.

---Edit:---

Here is my QMGR and CNL configuration's screens for SSL:
[image] 
[image]

Comment: Does the channel work without client authentication? This error can be thrown when the queue manager cannot find it's signer certificate too.

Comment: I'd like to set it to authenticate client, I registered client certificate in keystore under MQ channel dir, but I exactly do not understand how is the store related with given manager. I guessed it's done by it location.

Comment: I understand that you want client authentication, but first make the connection work without it. It sounds to me that you don't have the keystore set up correctly, it needs to be at the location specified in the key repository attribute of the QM. Where did you add the signing certificate of the queue manager?

Comment: @Attila Repasi thank you for valuable hint "Where did you add the signing certificate of the queue manager" I focus on problem with client certificate, but the issue was in Queue Manager certificate label I've highlighted above was not the same as label in key store. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

First I create certificate with own label but different than defaultgenerated in:

```
MQMGR->Properties->SSL->Certificate Label
```

which is `ibmwebspheremq<qmgr_name_lower_case>`, when I recreate certificate with same name specified:

```
runmqakm -cert -create -label ibmwebspheremqqm_qmname -stashed -dn "CN=corp.com,OU=DEV,OU=QMGR,O=CORP,L=member,ST=NC,C=US,EMAIL=name.surname@corp.com" -fips -db key.kdb -ca false
```

it start to communicate with server.

**EDIT**: See also [this](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21175024).

Comment: only to complete the response, it's possible to turn off client authentication completely by setting of CNL->Properties->SSL->SSL Authetication: Optional

Comment: How did you generate `keystore.jks` and `trusstore.jks` files? I did config this way and I'm getting `AMQ9637E: Channel is lacking a certificate.` from the broker. though.

Comment: @Sachith, I used existing stores, see the examples code on GitHub above (search "client Java class")